# Compiling a project that has sharekit in it

Tags: ios, ios6, sharing, sharekit

I am trying to compile my colleague's project in my computer. The project is compiling in his computer. When i copy over and compile, i get this errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DefaultSHKConfigurator", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ShareKitConfiguration in ShareKitConfiguration.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in VideoDetails.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKActionSheet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoDetails.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKFacebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoDetails.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_DefaultSHKConfigurator", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ShareKitConfiguration in ShareKitConfiguration.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Tried solving the errors but not able to solve it.. Need some help and guidance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have ShareKit as a submodule and importing the XCode project. In your git repo, call the following commands:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Then restart XCode and try to build it. If you still have issues, make sure your project is configured according to the ShareKit installation instructions found here: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit